# list of lists of column names to list of lists of df values

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Given the following list of lists representing column names:

```
names = [['a','b'],['c','c'],['b','c']]
```

and the following dataframe

```
df
   a  b  c
0  1  2  6
1  1  3  2
2  4  6  4
```

I would like to generate the list with the same dimensions as `names` with the following functionality:

```
lst = []
for idx, cols in enumerate(names):
  lst.append([])
  for col in cols:
    lst[-1].append(df.iloc[idx][col])

lst:
[[1,2],[2,2],[6,4]
```

I.e, the `names` array points to the pulled columns from `df` in the relevant `row_idx`.

I'm trying to avoid the nested loop.

Comment: The answer by @Ynjxsjmh is great, but just fyi, you do not have a nested loop in the sense of n^2 time complexity, since you only visit each col once.

Answer (score 1):

You can select multiple columns with list

```py
lst = []
for idx, cols in enumerate(names):
    lst.append(df.iloc[idx][cols].tolist())
# or list comprehension
lst = [df.iloc[idx][cols].tolist() for idx, cols in enumerate(names)]
```

```
print(lst)

[[1, 2], [2, 2], [6, 4]]
```

Comment: Can I somehow avoid looping over `names`? `names` length is the same as df's length

Comment: @InsDSt No idea.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that the length of `names` is same as dataframe length, and you don't want to loop over `names` nor perform nested loop. In that case, would looping over `range` be allowed?

```
index = range(len(names))

[df.iloc[i][names[i]].tolist() for i in index]
Out[16]: [[1, 2], [2, 2], [6, 4]]
```

Or `df.loc`

```
[df.loc[i,names[i]].tolist() for i in index]
Out[35]: [[1, 2], [2, 2], [6, 4]]
```